# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: http, iis-7, windows-server-2008, http-status-code-405

I have developed a site in ASP.NET 3.5

I had deployed it on Windows server 2008 and iis7. I was using evaluation version of Windows server 2008. Day before yesterday the evalution period expired and I formatted my machine and re-installed the Windows server 2008.

Now, when I deploy the site on IIS7 and try to access it then I get following error,

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar problem which turned out to be because facebook seem to make all requests as a POST and my page was a static html file, which (by default?) IIS7 will only serve by a GET request

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error as well after moving to a new IIS server which did not have PHP installed and trying to use a PHP script (from within an html file form).

Installing PHP fixed the issue.